# How we can disable fullscreen feature in Flash fallback of MediaElementJS?

Tags: flash, fullscreen, mediaelement.js, mediaelement, fallback

Please help to fix this bug when using Flash fallback:

Step 1: We click on flash player (Video is playing by flash fallback).
Step 2: Press TAB button on keyboard (button fullscreen in flash will have yellow border).
Step 3: Press SPACE button on keyboard (the controler will appear).

Is there a way to disable the fullscreen feature of the flash player?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hello everybody,
Please help me!
Thank you.
Regards,
Cuong Sky